# "Use Auto Property" quick action in Visual Studio 2019 available in some projects but not others

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The "Use Auto Property" quick action will be displayed in Visual Studio under the *lightbulb* icon when the code is something like this:

```cs
private string myProperty;

public string MyProperty
{
  get { return myProperty; }
  set { myProperty = value; }
}
```

However I have found that this context menu option will show for me in some VS solutions and not others even when I copy and paste the same code snippet between solutions, so I suppose that solution or project level setting affect whether this option is displayed, yet I cannot find what enables or disables it.

Note that I can see other quick actions such as "Replace 'MyProperty' with method" in all solutions, it is just the "Use Auto Property" action that I can't see displayed in the quick action context menu.

Comment: Does it vary by the target framework of the project, or by whether the project is SDK-style or not? If you think this is a bug, file it at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue is happening on Classes with the [Serializable] attribute, when I remove the attribute the "Use Auto Property" quick action displays correctly and it turns out that [this behaviour is intentional](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/34783)